# JNI and pthread

Tags: android-ndk

I'm calling JNI_OnLoad to save a the JavaVM* localy:

```
             JavaVM * and_jvm = NULL;
             jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
             {
                   and_jvm = vm;
                   return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
             }
```

When I start my thread I call

```
             void * thread_f (void * v)
             {
             jint attachResult = and_jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env,NULL);
             //The attachResult is 0.
             jclass my_class= (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("my/package/com/MyClass"));
             //my_class is 0
             if (my_class == 0)
                  return NULL;
             }
```

If I call NewGlobalRef out of the thread it returns a valid object.
What is wrong?

10xs,
Nahum

Comment: You are asking what is wrong when NewGlobalRef returns a valid object? What did you expect it to return? If 0 is valid result, then it means there is no such class - MyClass in package my.package.com

Comment: But the same call to NewGlobalRef from the main thread of the lib returns a valid jclass so I guess there is MyClass at package my.package.com

Comment: I don't understand. You are saying that "If I call NewGlobalRef out of the thread it returns a valid object" - so you are getting valid object when you call NewGlobalRef from thread, or what?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `NewGlobalRef` but with `FindClass`.

It is best to do all of your `FindClass` calls in `JNI_OnLoad`. This is because of some issue with classloaders... When you are on the new thread, a different classloader is used, and that's why the class cannot be found.

You could actually make `my_class` a global, create the `GlobalRef` in `JNI_OnLoad` and use it anywhere in your program without a problem.